# ng-options by default selected dynamic options

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class=" header-search pull-right">
            <section style="margin-top: 15px" class="col col-6">
                <label class="select">
                    <select style="width: 300px" ng-change="seletedCompanyChanged()"
                            ng-model="selectedCompanyId"
                            ng-options="value.CompanyId as value.Name for value in CompanyTempDDForHeder ">
                        <option value="" ng-selected="{{CompanyTempDDForHeder.Name}}">{{CompanyTempDDForHeder.Name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </section>
        </div>
```

Cod in Controller

```
var getCompaniesbyPassingLogin = function (data) {
        $scope.CompanyTempDDForHeder = data;
    }

    globalService.getCompanyDropDownForHeader(getCompaniesbyPassingLogin);
```

its working fine but i want to select by default 1st value in drop down  like this

```
<option value="" ng-selected="selected">Select Compnay</option>
```

how to select by default dynamic value in drop down?
here is my code.
is it possible?

Comment: Can you please post your angular code / full code.

Comment: You have initialize some value. In your controller, put `$scope.selectedCompanyId='default_value';`  where default value will be one the values in your dropdown. (assuming your controller take $scope service)

Comment: Also, use option value like this. This particular value will be selected by default. `<option selected value="name">Name</option>`

Answer (score 0):

`selectedCompanyId`, being the `ng-model`, allows you to set the default selected value.

In your AngularJS code, it should be something like that:

```
$scope.selectedCompanyId = "Company A";
```

From the [AngularJS documentations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select), it is stated that:

> The `select` directive is used together with `ngModel` to provide data-binding between the scope and the `<select>` control (including setting default values).

Also, there is no need for you to have the `<option>` line as `ng-options` (in `<select>`) will populate the dropdown list for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the default value with an `ng-init` directive. So something like this should work:

```
<select style="width: 300px" ng-change="seletedCompanyChanged()"
          ng-model="selectedCompanyId"
          ng-options="value.CompanyId as value.Name for value in CompanyTempDDForHeder"
          ng-init="selectedCompanyId=CompanyTempDDForHeder[0].CompanyId"> 
</select>
```

Note that when using the `ng-options` directive, you do not need the `<option>` elements, as this directive will create them for you.